# How do I listen for errors thrown in the log?

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how I would go about listening for errors in Java. What I want to do is upon an error being thrown to the console, the program will detect it and simplify it (stack-traces can be scary!).

Here is what I tried:

```
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)
            {
                // do some good stuff here, like logging or sending an alert email to the Support team
                System.out.println("EXCEPTION CAUGHT!");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

But unfortunately, it's not saying EXCEPTION CAUGHT! upon the error occurring. Should I be doing it this way, or is there some way to listen for the System.out log itself when it is updated?

Comment: This is just a way to handle the uncaught exceptions from a thread. You can do WHATEVER YOU CAN IMAGINE here. There's no right answer. Log4J has some solutions for logging. I've had my handlers send e-mails, create error reporting forms etc... I would specify what you need it to do. In general recording the errors is good practice.

Comment: The simplifying part, I think I can figure out. I'm just trying to trigger a method when an error is thrown without being caught. After that, I simplify it so that server owners will know what the error was (I'm coding this as a Bukkit plugin).

Comment: in your code -> `MyClass.doSomething(t, e);` You're basically doing that on the "uncaughtException" method. You can basically do anything there.

Comment: Isn't that what I tried...?

Comment: Yes, the method call is the listener. When an exception is thrown this is called. It is one in the same. If your errors are not being caught it is likely there is a thread that has its own exception handling or it is printing directly to the stack trace. Unroll the stacktrace and find where it is printing.

Comment: The thing is, it's not working for me. I'm not getting a printed message.

Comment: You should post the code you think is throwing the exception. Odds are it is being swallowed by another catch statement or a registered exception handler.

Comment: I just try any random function that causes an error. Example: UUID.fromString("ssjlajdkasfjsal djasl djsa dasdkas");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60357/discussion-between-daniel-b-chapman-and-colonelhedgehog).

Comment: Your handler cannot catch anything since Bukkit catches exceptions itself for  event handlers and commands and just logs them. You can probably work around this by making a custom `Command` (not `CommandExecutor`). Source reference: [players](https://github.com/Bukkit/CraftBukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/net/minecraft/server/PlayerConnection.java#L960) [console](https://github.com/Bukkit/CraftBukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/craftbukkit/CraftServer.java#L727) [command map](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/command/SimpleCommandMap.java#L182)

Answer (score 2):

For lack of an answer but a lot of discussion what's probably happening is your framework sets a custom handler which swallows your exception (almost every web framework for example).

Here's some code to illustrate how it works as there is a default handler and then each thread or thread group can have their own handler.

```
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


    public class Tests 
    {
        public static void main(String ... args)
        {       
            Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() 
            {

                @Override
                public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) 
                {
                    System.out.print("[Handler Handling]\t");
                    System.out.print(t.getName());
                    System.out.print("\n");
                    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
                    System.out.println("[End Handling]");
                }
            }); 

            new Thread()
            {
                {
                    //Disable this handler
                    this.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

                        @Override
                        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
                            System.out.print("[Different Handling]\t");
                            System.out.print(thread.getName());
                            System.out.print("\n");
                            throwable.printStackTrace(System.out);
                            System.out.println("[End Different Handler]");
                        }
                    });
                }
                public void run()
                {
                    throw new RuntimeException("This is thrown in the child thread.");
                }
            }.start();

            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e1) 
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            JFrame gui = new JFrame();
            gui.setSize(400, 300);
            gui.setTitle("Swing Thread");
            JButton error = new JButton("Throw Error");
            error.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
                    {
                        throw new RuntimeException("This exception happens in the Swing thread");
                    }

                });

            gui.add(error);
            gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            gui.setVisible(true);

            throw new RuntimeException("This is thrown in the main thread.");
        }
    }
```

**This will provide the following output (or something similar if you click a button):**

```
[Different Handling]    Thread-0
java.lang.RuntimeException: This is thrown in the child thread.
    at Tests$2.run(Tests.java:45)
[End Different Handler]
[Handler Handling]  main
java.lang.RuntimeException: This is thrown in the main thread.
    at Tests.main(Tests.java:77)
[End Handling]
[Handler Handling]  AWT-EventQueue-0
java.lang.RuntimeException: This exception happens in the Swing thread
    at Tests$3.actionPerformed(Tests.java:68)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    <...snipped for brevity...>
[End Handling]
```

So it is impossible to answer your question fully without more information. If you are, for example, using JavaFX there's a different pattern for handling uncaught exceptions. It depends entirely on your framework and situation. If you are, in fact, setting the handler on the main thread and starting there then this should work without issue.